# SQLAlchemy: give some execution_options parameter to all session's queries at once

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, soft-delete

### Original question

I have set up a soft deletion on SQLAlchemy 1.4 based on this example in the official doc [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/_modules/examples/extending_query/filter_public.html). The
`_add_filtering_criteria` filters out the soft-deleted objects whenever the `execute_state.execution_options` `"include_deleted"` is False.

At some point, I would like that some queries are able to search in the soft-deleted objects. I am able to do it per queries, i.e. specifying `query.execution_options(include_deleted=True)` but I would like to make all queries of a particular session include soft-deleted objects without having to specify it for each query.

I have tried to declare the `execution_options(include_deleted=True)` on the engine's creation but it does not work.

```
from sqlalchemy import orm

class SoftDeleted:
    deletion_date = Column(DateTime, nullable=True)

@event.listens_for(orm.Session, "do_orm_execute")
def _add_filtering_criteria(execute_state: orm.ORMExecuteState) -> None:
    """Intercepts all ORM queries. Adds a with_loader_criteria option to all
    of them.
    This option applies to SELECT queries and adds a global WHERE criteria
    (or as appropriate ON CLAUSE criteria for join targets)
    to all objects of a certain class or superclass.
    """
    if (not execute_state.is_column_load  
            and not execute_state.is_relationship_load
            and not execute_state.execution_options.get("include_deleted", False)):
        execute_state.statement = execute_state.statement.options(
            orm.with_loader_criteria(
                SoftDeleted,
                lambda cls: cls.deletion_date.is_(None),
                include_aliases=True,
            )
        )
engine = sa.create_engine(url, echo=False).execution_options(include_deleted=True)
session_factory = orm.sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = session_factory()

# let SomeClass be a class that inherits from the SoftDeleted mixin

myquery = session.query(SomeClass).get(1) 
# will not retrieve SomeClass with uid=1 if it is soft-deleted

myquery2 = session.query(SomeClass).execution_options(include_deleted=True).get(1) 
# will retrieve SomeClass with uid=1 even if it is soft-deleted
```

As I said, I would like that all queries of the session are able to include soft-deleted objects. Would someone know how I can do?

### Solution, thanks to snakecharmerb's answer

After snakecharmerb answers, I modified the following and I got the wanted behaviour

```
@event.listens_for(orm.Session, "do_orm_execute")
def _add_filtering_criteria(execute_state):
if (not execute_state.is_column_load
        and not execute_state.is_relationship_load
        and not execute_state.execution_options.get("include_deleted", False)
        and not execute_state.session.info.get("include_deleted", False)):
[...]
```

```
engine = sa.create_engine(url, echo=False) \
        .execution_options(include_deleted=include_deleted)

session_factory = orm.sessionmaker(
    bind=engine,
    info={'include_deleted':
          engine.get_execution_options().get('include_deleted', False)})
session = session_factory()
[...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set your flag in the engine's execution options, so you must retrieve it from there. The engine can be accessed through the session's `bind` attribute:

```
(Pdb) execute_state.session.bind.get_execution_options()
immutabledict({'include_deleted': True})
```

Your code does not error because `execute_state` has an `execution_options` attribute, but it contains other things:

```
(Pdb) execute_state.execution_options
immutabledict({'_sa_orm_load_options': <class 'sqlalchemy.orm.context.QueryContext.default_load_options'>, '_result_disable_adapt_to_context': True, 'future_result': True})
```

[Session](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session) objects (and [sessionsmakers](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.sessionmaker.__init__)) have an [info](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.info) attribute, a dictionary that you can populate as you wish.  This could used to pass the flag if you wanted to set the flag per session rather than per engine.

Comment: Hi snakecharmerb, thanks for your answer! I got that I could pass the `include_deleted` flag to the session/sessionmaker, but I don't understand how I can then make the session apply the given execution option without expliciting an `.execution_options()` to each query?

Comment: You don't need to specify it on the query - set it on the session and access it via execute_state in the listener